# React-Native Could not connect to development server

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I've been testing my project on my iPhone6s and it worked perfectly. But today Xcode and Node.js keeps giving me the 'Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBridge is undefined' error. 
I'm sure the IP address is correct, my phone is under the same Wifi network with server. The simulator works fine with the server ip. To test if it is something wrong with the project I start another AwesomeProject and changed the IP but still not working. Anyone know any possible solutions?

Comment: I've had issues connecting to local server at certain WiFi locations, just use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) to expose your local server publicly. Make sure to add the returned url to the AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: @BradBumbalough is the returned url something like  'xxxxxx.ngrok.io' ?

Comment: Yes, and if you did it right you don't need to reference the port. You would run `ngrok http 8081` to expose the port to ngrok, so it's bound to that port already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue in my office Wifi network connection also. This is because of the router configuration. There are two ways to make it work.

1. Expose the local server using `ngrok`. But, It will be slow since it is sending everything to server.
2. Connect your phone using USB cable and type the following command in the computer `adb reverce tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: I'm developing iOS version of the app so I guess adb won't work( and it did not work after i tried lol). I tried ngrok, is the 'xxxxxx.ngrok.io' my public ip? it's still not working if it is the public ip

Comment: Did you expose the `8081` port correctly? Type the `xxxxxx.ngrok.io:8081/index.ios.bundle` in the mobile browser. If you are not getting any text, then the problem is on computer side. If you are getting the js bundle, then problem is on the mobile side.